# ts-node with tsconfig-paths won't work when using esm

Tags: typescript, alias, tsconfig, ts-node

I couldn't figure out why `ts-node` isn't resolving the alias when esm is enabled

I made a tiny project trying to isolate the issue as much as possible

`package.json`

```json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",                                
    "baseUrl": "./",                                  
    "paths": {
      "$lib/*": [
        "src/lib/*"
      ]
    },
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  }
}
```

`test.ts`

```
import { testFn } from "$lib/module"

testFn()
```

`lib/module.ts`

```
export function testFn () {
  console.log("Test function")
}
```

command

```bash
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/test.ts
```

[Here's a minimal repo](https://github.com/unlocomqx/ts-node-paths-issue)

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @DDana Check the first line in my question, I linked to a solution

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately did not succeed. I wrote a comment there. If you can unblock me would really appreciate it https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/discussions/1450#discussioncomment-2560012

Comment: Just putting here OPs own answer [https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/discussions/1450#discussioncomment-1806115](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/discussions/1450#discussioncomment-1806115)

Comment: @Preda7or If you'd like to summarize or explain the solution, I will accept it as the solution. Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution from: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/discussions/1450#discussion-3563207

At the moment, the ESM loader does not handle TypeScript path mappings. To make it work you can use the following custom loader:

```
// loader.js
import {
  resolve as resolveTs,
  getFormat,
  transformSource,
  load,
} from "ts-node/esm";
import * as tsConfigPaths from "tsconfig-paths"

export { getFormat, transformSource, load };

const { absoluteBaseUrl, paths } = tsConfigPaths.loadConfig()
const matchPath = tsConfigPaths.createMatchPath(absoluteBaseUrl, paths)

export function resolve(specifier, context, defaultResolver) {
  const mappedSpecifier = matchPath(specifier)
  if (mappedSpecifier) {
    specifier = `${mappedSpecifier}.js`
  }
  return resolveTs(specifier, context, defaultResolver);
}
```

Then use the loader with:
`node --loader loader.js index.ts`

Caveat: This only works for module specifiers without an extension. For example, import `/foo/bar` works, but import `/foo/bar.js` and import `/foo/bar.ts` do not.

Remember to install these packages as well:

```
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
"tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.2",
```

## Updated: 09/11/2023

The new loader will automatically resolve the **index.(js|ts)**:

```
import { resolve as resolveTs } from 'ts-node/esm'
import * as tsConfigPaths from 'tsconfig-paths'
import { pathToFileURL } from 'url'

const { absoluteBaseUrl, paths } = tsConfigPaths.loadConfig()
const matchPath = tsConfigPaths.createMatchPath(absoluteBaseUrl, paths)

export function resolve (specifier, ctx, defaultResolve) {
  const match = matchPath(specifier)
  return match
    ? resolveTs(pathToFileURL(`${match}`).href, ctx, defaultResolve)
    : resolveTs(specifier, ctx, defaultResolve)
}

export { load, transformSource } from 'ts-node/esm'
```

Example:

```
Path: /src/modules/order/index.ts
Resolve: import orderModule from '@/modules/order';
```

Comment: don't forget to rexport `load` as well from `ts-node/esm` or else you'll get `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"`

Comment: Doesn't work with node 20 anymore: `Error [ERR_LOADER_CHAIN_INCOMPLETE]: "../loader.js 'resolve'" did not call the next hook in its chain and did not explicitly signal a short circuit. If this is intentional, include "shortCircuit: true" in the hook's return.`

Comment: @MarcJ.Schmidt it works well with node v20 on my side. Did you check the last update?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use esno `esno src/test.ts`

Comment: esno is another name for tsx, and tsx does not support emitting decorators metadata unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

You can use [@bleed-believer/path-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bleed-believer/path-alias) to execute your **ESM** project ([ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) is included as dependency):

```bash
npm i --save @bleed-believer/path-alias
```

To execute your source files with **ts-node**:

```bash
npx bb-path-alias ./src/test.ts
```

Assuming `"outDir": "./dist"`, to execute your transpiled code directly with node (bypassing ts-node):

```bash
npx bb-path-alias ./dist/test.js
```

If you don't want to use the library to execute your transpiled project, you can use [swc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@swc/core) (this transpiler resolves the path aliases), or you can use [tsc-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias) after transpile your project with **tsc**.

#### Note

I updated the method of use the library according the last update.